# Update issue using join in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, syntax-error

Good morning all,

Apologies if this has been addressed, I am attempting to run the following query. I have duplicated my table in order to create a join.

I have identified the null Propertyaddress in table A (28 cells had missing Property Addresses in table A). I then hope to insert addresses from PropertyAddress table B  by joining table A to table B.

Although the query joining table A to table B runs correctly, I am unable to update the table due to an operational error.

I am able to successfully run:

```
%%sql
SELECT A1.PropertyAddress, A1.ParcelID, B2.PropertyAddress, B2.ParcelID, IFNULL(A1.PropertyAddress, B2.PropertyAddress)
FROM Nashvillehousing A1
JOIN Nashvillehousing B2
ON A1.ParcelID = B2.ParcelID
AND A1.UniqueID <> B2.UniqueID
WHERE A1.PropertyAddress IS NULL
```

However, I can not run the following:

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: A1
[SQL: UPDATE A1
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(A1.PropertyAddress, B2.PropertyAddress)
FROM Nashvillehousing as A1
JOIN Nashvillehousing as B2
ON A1.ParcelID = B2.ParcelID
AND A1.UniqueID <> B2.UniqueID
WHERE A1.PropertyAddress IS NULL]
```

I appreciate any input!

I have tried different aliases, periods, underscores however my aliased tables are still not recognised for an UPDATE query.

I expect the missed values to be inserted into table A1 from table B2 as an updated table with no missing property addresses.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT!

Comment: Hi Stu, apologies for the use of exclamation mark to indicate I am appreciative of any time dedicated to acknowledging this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SQL Server's syntax for a join in the `UPDATE` statement.

The [correct syntax for SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) is:

```
UPDATE Nashvillehousing AS A1
SET PropertyAddress = B2.PropertyAddress
FROM Nashvillehousing AS B2
WHERE A1.ParcelID = B2.ParcelID AND A1.UniqueID <> B2.UniqueID
  AND A1.PropertyAddress IS NULL AND B2.PropertyAddress IS NOT NULL;
```

Also, I changed `IFNULL(A1.PropertyAddress, B2.PropertyAddress)` to just `B2.PropertyAddress` because the `WHERE` clause returns only rows with `null` in `PropertyAddress`.

Comment: Thank you forpas, this has worked successfully! I have book marked the link you sent. Unfortunately can't yet cast a vote but this definitely solved my issue.